# Send mail with Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel, spf, dkim

I try to send a mail with Laravel, but it doesn't work.
I've tried with Mandrill, mailgun and with gmail. Mandrill returns message like "missing SPF and DKIM".

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME="my gmail adress"
MAIL_PASSWORD="my gmail password"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_PRETEND=true
```

That is in my EmailController :

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', ['name' => 'Novice'], function($message){
    $message->to('f***@gmail.com', 'Fabien')->subject('Bienvenue !');
});
```

That is the route :

```
Route::resource('emails', 'EmailController');
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582267-About-SPF-and-DKIM#set-up-spf-and-dkim-for-your-sending-domains

Comment: I've already seen this page, but it's not working. I work on localhost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `MAIL_PRETEND` to `false`. This option is used to test sending mails without sending.

Also, since Laravel 5.2 the option `pretend` won't exists anymore.

> The `pretend` mail configuration option has been removed. Instead, use the `log` mail driver, which performs the same function as `pretend` and logs even more information about the mail message.

Read more: [Upgrading to 5.2](http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0), [Mail & Local Development](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#mail-and-local-development)

Comment: Hi, I tried with false value and without MAIL_PREVEND var but nothing happened.

Comment: @Swarovski Look in `config/mail.php` for `pretend` key and see what value is there, old Laravel could have `false` or `true` without integration with `.env` file.

Comment: @Svarowski In directory `storage/logs` you should have logs files. Try to send an e-mail and then see in `*.log` file what appered there. Also try to set `debug` to `true` value and check return value of sending mails (`$mail = Mail::send(...); var_dump($mail);`) and check what is a response. By default, SwiftMailer return number of recipients who were accepted for delivery (`swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php:74-92`).

Comment: When I dump $mail I get this message "int 1". Debug is on true and nothing new in .log file

Comment: @Swarovski maybe try to change port to `MAIL_PORT=465` and encryption to `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`. Also you could read more about Gmail configuration: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en .

The problem is not your code but your settings or your server or your Gmail account. SwiftMailer tells you that you send one e-mail to one recipient so in PHP everything works good.